# How to show a persistent EditText box in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Apologies if this question seems ignorant, I am very new to Android development.

I'm currently working on an app where the user will input a string as the main action. I currently am using an AlertDialog for this. However, I have noticed other apps (e.g.Hangouts, Todoist, etc.) Use a floating EditText box that appears above the keyboard and still allows access to the main activity beneath it. I have spent many an evening trying to find what this is, but to no avail. If someone could briefly explain where to find resources on this I would be very grateful.

Here is a picture from Todoist that demonstrates this.

[Floating EditText Example From Todoist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBWSa.png)

Comment: This looks like an `EditText` placed at the bottom of the layout. When the keyboard is up, the application window will be resized, and the `EditText` will now be just above the keyboard.

Comment: Like @Karakuri said, they don't use a floating edit text.  They use an edit text anchored to the bottom and resize when the keyboard is brought up.